# Ionic radio buttons: group disappears

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic radio buttons. My code:

```
<div class="item">
  <span class="input-label">Category : </span>
  <ion-radio ng-model="cssPre" ng-value=0>Saroj</ion-radio>
  <ion-radio ng-model="cssPre" ng-value=1>Sadhana</ion-radio>
  <ion-radio ng-model="cssPre" ng-value=2>Neha</ion-radio>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <span class="input-label">Work Place : </span>
  <ion-radio ng-model="workplace" ng-value="0">At clinic</ion-radio>
  <ion-radio ng-model="workplace" ng-value="1">At center</ion-radio>
</div>
```

When I click on the first group it works fine, but as soon as I select a work place from the second group my selected category disappears.

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, [take a look to this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmpEYv):

```
<div class="item">
    <span class="input-label">Category: </span><br />
    <span>Selected Value: {{cssPre}}</span>          
    <ion-radio name="cssPre" ng-model="cssPre" ng-value="0">Saroj</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio name="cssPre" ng-model="cssPre" ng-value="1">Sadhana</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio name="cssPre" ng-model="cssPre" ng-value="2">Neha</ion-radio>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <span class="input-label">Work Place : </span> <br />
    <span>Selected Value: {{workplace}}</span>                   
    <ion-radio name="workplace" ng-model="workplace" ng-value="0">At clinic</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio name="workplace" ng-model="workplace" ng-value="1">At center</ion-radio>
</div>
```

I only added the quotation marks to the first radio group and added the selected value of each group.

**UPDATE**: I added the `name` attribute for each ion-radio and fixed the [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmpEYv).

Comment: Thanks, but have you noticed that checkmark disappears. @manzapanza

Comment: @Shirin I updated my answer! I hope that I understood what means that 'disappears' :)